# How can I track issue from multiple different issue-trackers in a single place?

Tags: bug-tracking, issue-tracking, project-planning

Like a lot of open-source developers I find myself interacting with maybe dozens of **different projects' issue trackers** - some for work, some as a hobbyist; some frequently, some more rarely; sometimes to report bugs, sometimes to contribute patches, sometimes to follow others' bug reports that affect me, sometimes to organize my own work on my own projects.

The problem is, this activity is scattered across different web apps (**github, bitbucket, trac, bugzilla, mantis, jira**, ...) on different projects all over the web and there's no one place to check status of issues I'm trying to stay on top of.

I want one dashboard kind of app where I can browse, search, and sort (by updated date, priority, etc) everything assigned to me, or any bugs I've reported, or any bugs I'm watching for updates - across all projects - without having to manually re-enter all those issues into the dashboard: I want to just feed it a URL to an existing issue in some other tracker and it'll track that issue's status for me.

You could *almost* get there with just an RSS feed reader, except to be really useful the app would need to know more about the relevant metadata so you can sort and filter as needed.

*Has anybody built anything like that*?  Bonus if it provides write capabilities too, at least for common tasks like adding a comment, marking resolved.

I've never heard of any such thing, and I'm constantly wishing for it. If it doesn't exist I might have to take a crack at it.

Comment: How would this be different than a generic "issue tracker"?

Comment: Edited slightly to hopefully clarify. Can you re-read it and let me know if it's still not obvious? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will give you what you are looking for, but "[undock](http://web.archive.org/web/20120103081010/http://getundocked.com/)" supports multiple issue trackers... wether it supports them all in one interface I'm not sure, but may be worth checking it out.

edit: yes, it does support them in one interface - the next question is whether you want to read them off a mobile device :-)

Anyway, hope it is of some use.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that is the right general idea! (And since it's a web application it actually works fine on the desktop, I just tried it.) Some problems though: it doesn't support Trac, which is a deal-breaker for me; and it doesn't support github or bitbucket; and it doesn't seem to have a way to search across all the trackers you've registered, which is one of the big time-savers I was hoping for.   Also it limits you to registering 5 trackers.  And it's neither free as in beer nor free as in speech, although if it solved my problem fully that would be OK.

Comment: Hi slinkp - I recon this is worth discussing further - I am busy doing some work with countersoft on a gemini add on module and recon that building an "Issue-Tracker-Sync" module that centralises all your stuff into one app would be a useful tool. As a starting point, I would think we could do something along the lines of "select the tracker type" you want to sync with, select the projects in that tracker.. map user to user in remote tracker and set a sync schedule. (obviously an oversimplification) - drop me an email if you think this is a project worth tackling....Dave

Comment: Hi slinkp - scratch that idea, have a look here : http://tasktop.com/ - this should give you what you looking for in terms of functionality, although again, I'm not sure it connects ALL the trackers you mentioned.... I might still explore this idea in a bit more detail.

Comment: Tasktop looks like the right idea. And it supports Trac!  (Not bitbucket, github, or basecamp yet, though.)  Disappointing that it's not a web app (i.e. not available everywhere).